# Understanding why the DIR command behaves this way

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, dir

Why does:

```
dir "test.txt "
dir test.txt.
dir "test.txt    . .   ."
```

all lists test.txt with no error on Windows prompt?
Are there any other suffix that are ignored by Windows?

(please note that I added space, dot to the end of the filename)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows shell does not allow a file or folder name to end with dot or space. There are low level routines that automatically trim any trailing dots and/or spaces in many situations, including when used with `DIR`.

I found the following confirmation that names cannot end with dot or space in a Microsoft's Windows Dev Center article: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although
>   the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell
>   and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a
>   period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's what I thought. I would really like to find some source about the way Windows removes those characters. And especially if there are other characters concerned.

Comment: @Guillaume - See my updated answer with a reference. Based on the Microsoft article, I would say no other characters are affected.